# When "might" reported spam be sent to my carrier, and when "might" this incur an additional cost?

Tags: sms, spam

From https://support.google.com/messages/answer/9061432?hl=en

> **Learn about spam reports**
>
> If you report spam, Google will get a copy of up to 10 of the
> spammer's last messages so we can improve spam detection across Google
> products. Your past replies to the spammer are not sent to Google.
> Your name and phone number are not linked to the spammer’s messages.
> The spammer won't see or know about your report.
>
> Your spam report might create a separate “Spam reporting” conversation
> that sends a copy of the spammer’s number and most recent SMS message
> to your mobile carrier, which might have an additional cost.

A variant of this message appeared on my phone screen when I attempted to report a text message as spam.

Before going ahead with this, I have some questions.

1. When "might" these messages be sent to my mobile carrier?
2. Why can't Google tell me definitively whether or not this will happen?
3. Why don't I get to choose whether or not this happens?
4. When "might" this incur an additional cost?
5. Why doesn't Google know if it will?

I am not comfortable with the vague warnings that "stuff might happen" and that I "might be charged for it". These are not statements that inspire confidence; and without knowing under what circumstances they will take place, it is impossible to make an informed decision.

Comment: To 4.: Sending an SMS usually costs money (unless you have an SMS flat), I would assume that these are the "additional costs".

Comment: But this is a message *to the carrier*. You'd expect this to be free. And if it isn't, then there should be an option to *not* send it.

Comment: Even if it would be free in your case the general FAQ is for every Google user world wide and therefore has to cover hundred of different mobile network providers.  It might be the case that the SMS is not free for a lot of users.